# only 4 products are display in one row on magento home page, how can I make to display 6 products in one row?

Tags: php, magento

I'm using magento 1.7.0. I have installed a plugins for best seller and latest order products.
but the problem is its only showing 4 products on each row but to occupy the complete width on home page I want to display 6 products on each row.
I saw its phtml file it has only this much code

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalogextensions/lastordered_home_list')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: Check to see if they have included an option in the layout xml, then check the block code.

Comment: yeah I check but No such thing is mention in its layout xml file.

Comment: Can you tell us the extension you have installed or the contents of file or anything so that we can have a look at it.

Comment: only 2 lines of code is there, 0ne line for <h1> tag content and second line I have already mention.

Answer (score 0):

Extension may have set the columncount somewhere in the listing file or layout. You need to change it to from 4 to 6.
You will ind code like this -

```
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); 
$_columnCount = 4;
?>

OR 

<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
```